# Does the map $f:\emptyset\longrightarrow \{0\}$ exist?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

What function $f$ maps in the following way:
$$f:\emptyset\longrightarrow \{0\}$$

Comment: Does the cardinality of the domain count as a function?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is exactly one such function, which is the empty set.

**Explanation:**

By definition, functions $f : A \to B$ are certain subsets of the cartesian product $A\times B$ (for the defining property, see below). You can imagine this definition as identiying $f$ with its graph.
In your case, $A = \emptyset$, $B = X$ and $A \times B = \emptyset \times X = \emptyset$, whose only subset is the empty set.

The defining property is that for every $a\in A$ there is a unique element of $f$ having $a$ as its first component. In our case $f = \emptyset$, this condition is vacuously true.

Answer (score 6):

The only subset of the cartesian product $\,\emptyset\times X\;,\;\;X$ **any** set, is the only function $\,\emptyset\to X\,$